# ASp.net dll to PHP: Is it possible to convert an ASP.net dll to php extension

Tags: php, asp.net, dll, php-extension

Is it possible to convert an ASP.net dll to php extension? I tried googling but did not find any solution. Someone please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. You'll have to completly rewrite it in C or C++(?). ASP.net dlls run on the .net runtime, whereas php is a native program, the extensions are written in C.

Comment: Thanks Femaref. Any other work around possible other than re-writing it to c or c++ ?